# blazor with vs code

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have created a new blazor app using this command

```
dotnet new blazorhosted -o MyFirstBlazor
```

when opening the project with vs code and debug with ctr+f5

show the following error

```
C:\Users\admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\RazorCompilation.targets(184,5): error : rzc generate exited with code 1. [E:\Blazor\MyFirstBlazor\MyFirstBlazor.Client\MyFirstBlazor.Client.csproj]

Build FAILED.

C:\Users\admin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\RazorCompilation.targets(184,5): error : rzc generate exited with code 1. [E:\Blazor\MyFirstBlazor\MyFirstBlazor.Client\MyFirstBlazor.Client.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

and in the startup.cs file this error exists

```
 app.UseBlazor (Client.Startup>();
```

the intellisense couldn't recognize Client namespace
and show this message

```
 "The type or namespace name 'Client' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Blazor 0.7.0 that is from Dez/2018. A lot of new features and bug fixes have been added since.

I recommend you to download .Net Core 3.0 Preview 6. You will be able to create a project and run it without issues:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0

To work with the Preview 6 you will have to use the latest Visual Studio Preview release:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

Or alternatively  enable .NET Core SDK previews in Visual Studio.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-tooling-update-for-visual-studio-2017-version-15-9/

Answer (score 0):

I have a project with Blazor 0.7.0 too, since I'm reading a book called "Blazor Revealed". 
I have it working due to having NET Standard 2.0.3 installed. 
Take a look at the image attached
[image]